# How to change 2 different Bootstrap Modals' background colors?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal

When a Bootstrap modal is created, .modal-backdrop is added to the end of the HTML to create the background color. I can switch the color manually by just changing that class's color, however I'd like to switch the color of that class depending on which of the 2 modals have been triggered.

I'm currently using a sibling selector to try and differentiate which color I'd like, but regardless of which modal is called it now shows #000.

CSS:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.card-modal ~ .modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: How does those 2 differs? ... position in markup, siblings and/or have a unique class?

Comment: I tried to add a unique class .card-modal to the second modal HTML (highlighted), so that when that one is called the .modal-backdrop class appended at the bottom uses the #000 instead. Problem is, now both modals end up with #000, including the first modal HTML which does not have the unique class .card-modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".modal1").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('.modal-backdrop').css('background', 'red');
});

$(".modal1").on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('.modal-backdrop').css('background', '#000');
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  padding: 15px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
}
h4,
modal-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.no-borders {
  border: 0px;
}
.body-message {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #2086c1;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #2086c1;
  border-color: transparent;
}
.btn-primary:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.model1 .modal-backdrop {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Bootstrap Modal Example</h1>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal1">
    Modal 1
  </button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal Content: begins -->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header no-borders">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel"></h4>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal Body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="body-message centered"><strong>Modal 1 here.</strong>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Modal Content: ends -->

  </div>

</div>

<!---------------------->
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Bootstrap Modal Example</h1>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2">
    Modal 2
  </button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal2" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal Content: begins -->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="body-message">
          <h4>Modal 2 here.</h4>
          <p>How to change this background colour?</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Modal Content: ends -->

  </div>

</div>
```

**Update**

Properties of Bootstrap modals :

- `shown.bs.modal` is fired when your modal is opened
- `hidden.bs.modal` is fired when your modal is closed

What I'm doing is, whenever you try to open a bootstrap model a div with class modal-backdrop is added and I'm simply changing that backdrop's color to whatever you like. And whenever you try to remove your model that div will be removed. So you need to manage it every time. And as per your requirement if you have more then two models then every one's color should be different (at least what I interpreted).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shalin, can you explain your jquery a little bit? I can see you have 2 separate classes (modal1, modal2) on each modal HTML, but in your jquery it seems like you just change modal1's color. Why do you need to have 2 css classes if you're just switching it in JQuery? Also, how does 'shown.bs.modal' vs 'hidden.bs.modal' know which modal you're referring to? Finally, if you open Modal 1, you'll notice there's still a flicker of the #000 before it changes to red. How can we prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the modal dialogs programmatically, you can do this:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.keyboard = false;
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').$backdrop.css('background-color', 'red'); <-- Set color!
```

Besides opening the modal dialog, you can define various options for the backdrop behavior. For example, if a click outside of the dialog should or should not close the modal dialog. The same applies to pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on your keyboard.

Additionally, you can set CSS properties of the backdrop, such as the `background-color` (*see example above*). **To reference the modal dialog, however, you need to define a unique id on the modal in your HTML code.** To solve your problem, the last line is sufficient. I'm just setting the additional options here, to showcase this capability.